# VS2010 C++ MFC Hide Toolbar

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm having trouble understanding just how the View Menu turns off the Standard Toolbar in terms of code.

If I understand correctly, the standard toolbar is defined in the .rc file as follows:

```
IDR_MAINFRAME TOOLBAR 16, 15
BEGIN
    BUTTON      ID_FILE_NEW
    BUTTON      ID_FILE_OPEN
    BUTTON      ID_FILE_SAVE
    SEPARATOR
    BUTTON      ID_EDIT_CUT
    BUTTON      ID_EDIT_COPY
    BUTTON      ID_EDIT_PASTE
    SEPARATOR
    BUTTON      ID_FILE_PRINT
    BUTTON      ID_APP_ABOUT
END
```

Similarly the View Menu, which allows you to turn the Standard Toolbar on and off is defined as follows:

```
IDR_MAINFRAME MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&New\tCtrl+N",                ID_FILE_NEW
        MENUITEM "&Open...\tCtrl+O",            ID_FILE_OPEN
        MENUITEM "&Close",                      ID_FILE_CLOSE
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "P&rint Setup...",             ID_FILE_PRINT_SETUP
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "Recent File",                 ID_FILE_MRU_FILE1,GRAYED
        MENUITEM SEPARATOR
        MENUITEM "E&xit",                       ID_APP_EXIT
    END
    POPUP "&View"
    BEGIN
        POPUP "&Toolbars and Docking Windows"
        BEGIN
            MENUITEM "<placeholder>",           ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR
        END
        MENUITEM "&Status Bar",                 ID_VIEW_STATUS_BAR
        POPUP "&Application Look"
        BEGIN
            MENUITEM "Windows &2000",           ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_WIN_2000
            MENUITEM "Office &XP",              ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_XP
            MENUITEM "&Windows XP",             ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_WIN_XP
            MENUITEM "Office 200&3",            ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_2003
            MENUITEM "Visual Studio 200&5",     ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_VS_2005
            MENUITEM "Visual Studio 200&8",     ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_VS_2008
            POPUP "Office 200&7"
            BEGIN
                MENUITEM "&Blue Style",         ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_2007_BLUE
                MENUITEM "B&lack Style",        ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_2007_BLACK
                MENUITEM "&Silver Style",       ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_2007_SILVER
                MENUITEM "&Aqua Style",         ID_VIEW_APPLOOK_OFF_2007_AQUA
            END
        END
    END
    POPUP "&Help"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&About Emergence...",          ID_APP_ABOUT
    END
END
```

Now my reasoning is this....in order for the MENUITEM that allows you to toggle the Standard Toolbar on and off to work, ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR must somehow reference the toolbar definition itself. I have searched the entire project and nowhere can I find where ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR is associated with the Standard Toolbar definition. Surely there must be some relationship linking ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR to the definition of IDR_MAINFRAME TOOLBAR 16, 15 in order to toggle it on and off??

If not, could you kindly explain how ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR turns off the Standard Toolbar?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR` is a Standard Command ID. [TN022: Standard Commands Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11861byt.aspx)
 explains how these are handled. In case of the `ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR`:

> `ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR` Toggles the toolbar on and off
>
> CFrameWnd handles this command and the update-command UI handler to toggle the visible state of the toolbar. The toolbar must be a child window of the frame with child window ID of `AFX_IDW_TOOLBAR`. The command handler actually toggles the visibility of the toolbar window. `CFrameWnd::RecalcLayout` is used to redraw the frame window with the toolbar in its new state. The update-command UI handler checks the menu item when the toolbar is visible.
>
> Customization of this command handler is not recommended. If you wish to add additional toolbars, you will want to clone and modify the command handler and the update-command UI handler for this command.

The connection is etablished in your `CMainFrame::OnCreate` override. It calls `m_wndToolBar.CreateEx`, leaving out the final optional parameter: The control ID `AFX_IDW_TOOLBAR`. It then proceeds to call `m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME)`. This constructs the toolbar from your `TOOLBAR` resource with ID `IDR_MAINFRAME`.

Comment: I was wondering though, what if there are multiple toolbars??

Comment: "If you wish to add additional toolbars, you will want to clone and modify the command handler and the update-command UI handler for this command."..................skimmed over this......still not sure what it means though....

Comment: If you wish to add additional toolbars, things get messy. In other words: Don't.

Comment: ic.....so if i understand correctly, the definition of the toolbar, i.e. IDR_MAINFRAME TOOLBAR 16, 15......is there purely to define what buttons appear in the toolbar?

Comment: The resource script defines the button layout and their command IDs. The command IDs are later assigned to the toolbar buttons to generate appropriate `WM_COMMAND` messages. The `RT_TOOLBAR` resource type is a private MFC resource type - the syntax is not officially documented. [Toolbar Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9hbax0b.aspx#_core_editing_the_toolbar_resource) has a few hints, though.

Comment: "The command IDs are later assigned to the toolbar buttons to generate appropriate WM_COMMAND messages." Could you please elaborate where and how this done?

Comment: This is done in `CMFCToolBar::LoadToolBarEx` (called from `CMFCToolBar::LoadToolBar`), in particular the line `bResult = SetButtons(pItems, pData->wItemCount);`. `pItems` is an array of `UINT`s. Those are the control IDs `ID_FILE_NEW`, etc. The full code can be found in afxtoolbar.cpp.