# How to show/hide a Toolbar (the ENTIRE bar, not an individual button) dynamically in MFC?

Tags: mfc, toolbar

I created an SDI app with a single menu and a single toolbar in MFC:

[image]

I am supposed to show/hide the toolbar dynamically *via* this code:

```
...
m_wndToolBar.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
...
```

It did visually hide the toolbar but left a blank, seemingly still working space in the dock region that blocks the main view repositioning. And, when I try to drag the menu, it can dock to the top and bottom line just like the toolbar is there.

[image]

I must have missed some necessary steps. So how can I "really" remove the toolbar and raise the main view close to the menu?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526658/vs2010-c-mfc-hide-toolbar You probably need a call to CFrameWnd::RecalcLayout after you have deleted the toolbar.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Calling `ShowPane` does all that work for you, if the second argument is `FALSE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a (relatively) recent version of MFC, and that your `m_wndToolBar` member is a `CMFCToolBar` (or derived therefrom), then you should use [the `ShowPane()` member function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdockablepane-class?view=msvc-170#showpane), rather than the more general `ShowWindow()` member. Using the former allows the Framework to make the required adjustments to the docking system.

From the linked document:

> Call this method instead of the CWnd::ShowWindow when showing or
> hiding dockable panes.

(Note that a `CMFCToolBar` is derived from `CPane` *via* the `CMFCBaseToolBar` class.)

In your call to `ShowPane()`, the first argument will be `TRUE` to show the toolbar or `FALSE` to hide it; the other two arguments will most likely be `FALSE`, as you want to readjust the docking layout *immediately* and you generally don't want to `activate` a toolbar.

So:

```cpp
//...
m_wndToolBar.ShowPane(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE); // Hide toolbar
//...
```

Or:

```cpp
//...
m_wndToolBar.ShowPane(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE); // Show toolbar
//...
```

Note also that `ShowPane()` (or, rather, a version of it) is called by the Framework's default handler for a show/hide menu item with the ID of any toolbar (which toggles its visibility); from "afxframewndex.cpp":

```cpp
BOOL CFrameWndEx::OnPaneCheck(UINT nID)
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);
    CBasePane* pBar = GetPane(nID);
    if (pBar != NULL)
    {
        ShowPane(pBar, (pBar->GetStyle() & WS_VISIBLE) == 0, FALSE, FALSE);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! and thank you for correcting my English...